# Converting 1D CNN from Keras to Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I am trying to make a switch from Tensorflow Keras to Pytorch.

The shape of my Input dataset is `(-1,128,6)`

I have the following model in keras:

```
serverModel = Sequential()
serverModel.add(Conv1D(196,  16, activation='relu',name = 'base1',input_shape=(128,6), padding='same'))
serverModel.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=4, padding='same',name = 'base2'))
serverModel.add(Flatten(name = 'flatten'))
serverModel.add(Dense(1024, activation = 'relu'))
serverModel.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
serverModel.add(Dense(activityCount, activation='softmax'))
```

In words, The convolution layer has 196, 16 by 1 filters. the inputs are tensor of length 128 over 6 dimensions.

I'm a bit confused with the documentation (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv1d)

what is the in `in_channels, out_channels` that I need to specify for the 1DCNN in PyTorch? A full conversion would be very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: How is 16 by 1 filter a 1DConv? 1DConv should have a 1D shape like 16. Are you considering 1 as input channels?

Comment: Hi @dumbPy, I added an image for further clarification. Yes, It is a 16 by 1 filter. But I suppose you can just say it's a 1DConv with a kernel of 16. 
There are 6 channels.
The image only shows 3

Comment: Then `in_channels` is the input channels of the data, here 6. `out_channels` is the output channels, i.e., number of feature maps. Here 196.

Comment: How can I specify the length of my data segment? it's 128 over 6 channels

Comment: In convolution operation, you don't. It does matter though when you flatten. Hence you will have to calculate the output size of the conv operations and then determine the flattened size and make fully connected layer accordingly.